# Why is Kinetic Energy in Energy-Distance graph linear, but parabolic in Energy-Time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Specifically, the projectile (falling off a table) problem. The graph of the Energy-Distance is linear, but I don't understand why. Isn't $KE = (1/2)mv^2$?

Comment: If you plot KE against velocity (not distance), the graph should be a parabola.

Comment: You mention the graph of energy-**distance** but compare with an energy-**velocity** formula. Those aren't comparable. Rather, find an energy-**distance** formula or expression to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a free fall, classically the potentional in height transform into energy in KE.
Thus KE linear with respect to height(distance $\Delta KE=mg\Delta h$).

However, as for time, notice your object is accelerating as $\Delta h=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, thus parabolic.